# pyqt interactive gridlayout

Tags: python, pyqt

i want to use a grid layout with pyqt6 to setup a test sequence. Everytime the "+" button is pressed i want to add a line with comboboxes. Somehow it only will place the first line and then it wil not add more. I do not get any error.

```
def add_line(self):
    print("Add line is pressed")
    self.item_row_tool.append(self.combobox_tools)
    self.item_row_param.append(self.combobox_param)
    
    self.layout.addWidget(self.item_row_tool[self.count_rows],self.count_rows+1,0)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.item_row_param[self.count_rows],self.count_rows+1,1)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)
    self.count_rows+=1
```

I do not understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: You seem to be adding the same widgets every time, instead of creating completely new ones. Widgets cannot be copied.

Comment: You are right. I now make a new widget and fill it with a list